# Кнопки или ссылки в шапке сайта WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Каким образом можно осуществить (с помощью каких операторов WordPress, php или javascript) переход на другую страницу, кликнув по кнопке (элементе шапки)?

Сопутствующий вопрос по дизайну.

Что лучше:

1. использовать ссылки (`<a href>`) в шапке сайта (с подсвечивающимся background и изменяющимся цвете текста ссылок);
2. использовать кнопки в шапке сайта (`<button>`);
3. использовать кнопки и ссылки одновременно для каждого элемента сайта?

Comment: `<a href>`? Вы про это?

Comment: @IgorR. да (и про `<button>`).

Comment: "Что лучше" — что Вам больше подходит, то и используйте.

Comment: @IgorR. Каким образом можно осуществить (с помощью каких операторов WordPress, php или javascript) переход на другую страницу, кликнув по кнопке (элементе шапки)?

Comment: Почитайте азы — "как сделать ссылку в HTML". Причем тут PHP, WordPress?

Comment: @IgorR. не по ссылке, а по кнопке (`<button id='mybutton'></button>` в html  и `$('#mybutton').on('click', ...)` в js)

Answer (score 0):

Для обычного перехода на другую страницу по клику достаточно использовать `<a href="/your-url">Текст или картинка или какой-либо элемент</a>`.

Учтите, что внутри тега `A` нежелательно использовать блочные теги, такие как `DIV`, такой код не будет валидным, хотя и будет работать.

Придать цвет ссылке или менять фон при наведении мышкой на ссылку необходимо через CSS.